# Вывод строки из TXT с последующим удалением Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется txt файл, содержимое

```
1:login1:password1 
2:login2:password2
3:login3:password3
4:login4:password4
...
```

Никакой последовательности нет, каждый раз разные данные, но формат такой.

Программа должна считать 1 строку и выводить ее так(пример, если берем 1 строку):

```
1
login1
password1
```

Далее программа должна удалять эту строку, т.е после выполнения программы содержимое txt файла:

```
2:login2:password2
3:login3:password3
4:login4:password4
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Файл скрипта и test.txt должны лежать в одной папке

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as file:
    lines = list(file)
    first_line  = lines[0]
    print(*first_line.split(':'), sep='\n')

with open('test.txt', 'w') as file:
    for line in lines:
        if line != first_line:
            file.write(line)
```

Comment: `file.close()` должно выполниться на выходе из блока with, так что избыточно. Вместо `for line in lines:` с условием, естественно, `for line in lines[1:]:` без условия... ну а на самом деле, конечно же, никакого цикла, просто `file.write("".join(lines[1:]))`